# pip fail to install javabridge

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `javabridge` using `pip` (`pip install javabridge`) but the following error appear:

> InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\windows\temp\pip_build_user\javabridge\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   c:\windows\temp\pip-46k2_w-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\windows\temp\pip_build_user\javabridge

How I could solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons that pip doesn't work, but as a backup you can manually install.

1. Download .tar.gz file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javabridge).
2. Unzip and un-tar to a folder ([7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) works well)
3. Navigate to folder from command line or powershell
4. run `python setup.py install`